# using PHP variables in html tag

Tags: php, html

I get a variable from PHP code which is a webpage link, and want to use that in html tag.
For example:

```
<?php 
  $link;

  ...
  $link = $client->api();
?>
 <a href= "<?php $link ?>" > LINK </a>
```

How can I get the link value in html tag?
Thank you!

Comment: because you need to set $link value to href, you must use echo and not just $link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have html file  then fist change the extention  .php  in place of .html

eg.  you have test.html then change that  to test.php

after that  you use the same code  as

```
<?php $link='http://stackoverflow.com' ?>

<a href= "<?php echo $link; ?>" > LINK </a>
```

Hope  this will help  you

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<a href= "<?php echo $link; ?>" > LINK </a>
```

echo it `echo $link;`

Alternatively, short hand would be:

```
<a href= "<?= $link; ?>" > LINK </a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must echo the value ... also, don't forget to escape it:

```
<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">LINK</a>
```

Since PHP 5.4 it's also safe to use [short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag):

```
<a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">LINK</a>
```

Comment: I would rather use htmlentities instead of htmlspecialchars

Comment: @Raubi No you would rather not use `htmlentities()` unless have a really good reason. For almost all situations `htmlspecialchars()` is sufficient and the correct way ™.

Answer (score 0):

Or in short way:

```
<a href="<?= $link; ?>">LINK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me 
you have to call the function (echo) in HTML Tag ... that all , good luck.

```
enter <a href= "<?php echo $link; ?>" > LINK </a> here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href= "<?php echo $link; ?>" > LINK </a>
```

or

```
<?php

echo '<a href= "'.$link.'"> LINK </a>';

?>
```