# How to insert a variable in the middle of an img src string using echo in PHP

Tags: php

How do you insert a variable in **the middle** of an HTML string in an echo statement in PHP?

Non-working Example:

```
<?php
$amount = 50
$ordernumber = 123

echo "<img src="sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=<?php echo $amount;?>&ordernum=<?php echo $ordernumber;?> style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;" />"

?>
```

$amount and $ordernumber are the variables I am trying to insert in the middle of the above example.

Desired output wound be:

```
<img src="sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=50&ordernum=123 style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using PHP variables in html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427989/using-php-variables-in-html-tag)

Comment: Actually your desired output is syntactically incorrect HTML ??

Comment: Try with echo "<img src="sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=".$amount."&ordernum=".$ordernumber." style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;" />"

Comment: Instead of outputting long(er), largely static parts of HTML code with echo, you should familiarize yourself with https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Hi Ankur. No, unfortunately not. Your example echos the variable only without the rest of the image string before or after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really about the correct use of quotes and whether to echo it out from within PHP or to stop the PHP interpreter and output the HTML raw.

One way

```
<?php
$amount = 50
$ordernumber = 123

echo "<img src='sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=$amount&ordernum=$ordernumber' style='height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;' />";
```

Other way

```
<?php
$amount = 50
$ordernumber = 123
?>

<img src="sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=<?php echo $amount;?>&ordernum=<?php echo $ordernumber;?>" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;" />
```

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for your answer. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt comment :)

use this one

```
$amount = "50";
$ordernumber = "123";

echo '<img src="sale.php?profile=1&saleamt="".$amount."&ordernum=".$ordernumber." style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $amount = 50;
    $ordernumber = 123;
    echo "<img src='sale.php?profile=1&saleamt=$amount&ordernum=$ordernumber' style='height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;' />";
    ?>
```

**php variable rules :**

```
1.A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the variable
2.A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character
3.A variable name cannot start with a number
4.A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
5.Variable names are case-sensitive ($age and $AGE are two different variables)
6.Put semicolon end of the line.
```